# When using Gulp to build a solution, what does “MSBuild failed with code 1” mean?

Tags: habitat, gulp

I am getting error in Gulp while build the solutions.

I already given a permission for folder or sub folder and also update the gulp-config.js.

```
    var config = {
    websiteRoot: instanceRoot + "\\",
    sitecoreLibraries: instanceRoot + "\\bin",
    licensePath: instanceRoot + "\\App_Data\\license.xml",
    packageXmlBasePath: 
    ".\\src\\Project\\Basekit\\code\\App_Data\\packages\\basekit.xml",
    packagePath: instanceRoot + "\\App_Data\\packages",
    solutionName: "Basekit",
    buildConfiguration: "Debug",
    buildToolsVersion: 15.0,
    buildMaxCpuCount: 0,
    buildVerbosity: "minimal",
    buildPlatform: "Any CPU",
    publishPlatform: "AnyCpu",
    runCleanBuilds: false
};

<PropertyGroup>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == 
 ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == 
''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion) 
</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

 <Import Project="
   $(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" 
  Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />

  <Import Project=
  "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\ 
  Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have hardcoded path for *targets* in your **Basekit.Foundation.Logging.csproj** file in `Import` section. Something like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Replace this line with this section (dynamic version checking):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```